Not sure how to resolve this issue with the python code
I'm using whisper to transcribe audio to text. I decided to use distil -whisper to speed it up. I've been trying to follow the instructions on Hugging Face but keep getting an error. I'm running this code sequentially and there are no issues.
!pip install virtualenv
!virtualenv myenv
!myenv/bing/pip install datasets
!source myenv/bin/activate
!myenv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
!myenv/bin/pip install --upgrade transformers accelerate datasets[audio]

But then I add this code and I get an error.

import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq, AutoProcessor, pipeline
from datasets import load_dataset


device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
torch_dtype = torch.float16 if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.float32

model_id = "distil-whisper/distil-large-v3"

model = AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq.from_pretrained(
    model_id, torch_dtype=torch_dtype, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, use_safetensors=True
)
model.to(device)

processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)

pipe = pipeline(
    "automatic-speech-recognition",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=processor.tokenizer,
    feature_extractor=processor.feature_extractor,
    max_new_tokens=128,
    torch_dtype=torch_dtype,
    device=device,
)

dataset = load_dataset("distil-whisper/librispeech_long", "clean", split="validation")
sample = dataset[0]["audio"]

result = pipe(sample)
print(result["text"])


Traceback:
ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6c882f0cb9bd> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import torch
      2 from transformers import AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq, AutoProcessor, pipeline
----> 3 from datasets import load_dataset
      4 
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets'

I didn't get an error when I installed datasets so I don't understand why I'm getting an error now.

Looks like an import issue. Its not recognizing the datasets module import. You likely need an __init__.py  which is used to mark a directory as a Python package (i.e., datasets). It makes it so the file within this directory can be initialize as part of the same package when it is imported.
